PHP Google Meet Space creation meet api and service account Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied on resource Space (or it might not exist)
My code:
// Create a client.
$spacesServiceClient = new SpacesServiceClient([
    'credentials' => '../shortnet-207309-9a0b32f2b4de.json',
    'scopes' => ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/meetings.space.created'],
]);

// Prepare the request message.
$request = new CreateSpaceRequest();
$response = $spacesServiceClient->createSpace($request);
return response()->json($response, 200);

but I got an error:

{ "message": "Permission denied on resource Space (or it might not
exist)", "code": 7, "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", "details": [] }

what is wrong here? I am first time trying to integrate this google meet rest API.
I am using "google/apps-meet": "^0.2.3".

Did you find a solution?

Try to solve the problem with this solution, clarifying that if you have Windows, you apply lines 1 and 3 and it works the same.
php artisan cache:clear
chmod -R 777 storage/
composer dump-autoload


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
